# Add array with the same value

Tags: php, arrays

I need help or advice on how to add or combine the value of array with same key.

For example:

```
Array(
    [price] => 123
    [category] => Fiction
    [bookname] => Any-Book
    [type] => Futuristic 
)
Array (
    [price] => 145
    [category] => Fantasy
    [bookname] => Any-Book
    [type] => Futuristic
)
```

Through many attempt I was not able to achieve the result I wanted
it should be:

```
Array (
    [price] => 268
    [category] => Fantasy/Fiction
    [bookname] => Any-book
    [type] => Futuristic
)
```

I just need to combine the two they are essentially the same thing or needed to be bundled.

Comment: What is the same key? bookname? What if types are different?

Comment: switch cases based on the type of the 2 element

Comment: Will there ever be more than two arrays to combine? Will there ever be other key/value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my contribution, using `array_walk`, and making a few assumptions about the rules for the merge:

```
$a = Array(
    'price' => 123,
    'category' => 'Fiction',
    'bookname' => 'Any-Book',
    'type' => 'Futuristic'
);
$b = Array (
    'price' => 145,
    'category' => 'Fantasy',
    'bookname' => 'Any-Book',
    'type' => 'Futuristic'
);

array_walk ($a,
    function (&$v, $k, $comp) {
        if (is_int($v)) {
            $v = $v + $comp[$k];
        } else {
            if ($comp[$k] != $v) {
                $v = "$v/" . $comp[$k];
            }
        }
    }, $b);

var_dump($a);
```

The assumptions are: if the value in array `$a` is `int`, then sum it with the equivalent in `$b`. If the value is not `int`, compare it with the equivalent in `$b`, and if it matches leave it alone; otherwise concatenate wtih `/`.

Comment: Your solution is far more elegant than mine but you forgot float type

Comment: Thank you! we have identical codes! I messed up something on the condition.This is by far, the best answer.

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure of the type of your arrays and that they have the same keys :

```
 <?php
$a = array('price' => 123,
     'category' => 'Fiction',
     'bookname' =>'Any-book', 
     'type' => 'Futuristic');

      $b = array('price' => 145,
     'category' => 'Fantasy',
     'bookname' =>'Any-book', 
     'type' => 'Futuristic');



function mergeSameArray(array $a, array $b){
    $c = array();
    foreach($a as $key => $valueA){
        $typeA = gettype($valueA);
        $typeB = gettype($b[$key]); //$valueB
        if($typeB == $typeA){
            if($typeB == "double" || $typeA == "integer"){
                $c[$key] = $valueA+ $b[$key];
            }
            elseif($typeB == "string"){
                if($valueA == $b[$key]){
                    $c[$key] = $valueA;
                }
                else{
                    $c[$key] = $valueA.'/'. $b[$key];
                }
            }
            else{
                $c[$key] = "error nor string nor number";          
            }
        }
        else{
            $c[$key] = "error not same type";
        }

    }
    return $c;

}

    $arraySum = mergeSameArray($a,$b);
    print_r($arraySum);
```